# Ember.js link-to helper doesn't update URL correctly

Tags: ember.js

I'm having a fairly annoying problem with the `link-to` helper in Ember.js (latest build). No matter what I do, I'm getting `undefined` in the URL, which not only looks dumb, but makes it impossible to refresh the page. I have the following in my template:

```
{{#link-to 'organizations.organization.projects.index' this}}
    Projects
{{/link-to}}
```

`this` being a reference to an organization model. When I use this, Ember.js generated a link that points to `/organizations/undefined/organization.organization.projects`. However, if I clink on the link, it still takes me to the page with the model resolved. Same thing happens when I replace `this` with `model`.

But, if I replace `this` with `id`, the link it generates is correct: `/organizations/ORG_1/organization.organization.projects`. But when I click on the link, the URL no longer shows `ORG_1`, it shows `undefined`. But it still manages to resolved the model correctly.

The model with id `ORG_1` is a valid model. It's not undefined, it's not null and it's fully loaded. There's nothing wrong with the model, yet Ember.js refuses to correctly place its ID in the URL, but manages to use its data in templates just fine.

Does anybody have any idea what's causing this?

Here's my router, for reference. (I know, the routes are deeply nested. This application is going to be very large.)

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    // route('application')
    // route('index') -- main dashboard

    this.route('settings');

    this.resource('organizations', function() {
        // route('index') -- organization selector page
        this.resource('organizations.organization', { path: '/:organizationId' }, function() {
            // route('index') -- organization dashboard
            this.resource('organizations.organization.projects', function() {
                // route('index') -- project selector page
                this.resource('organizations.organization.projects.project', { path: '/:projectId' }, function() {
                    // route('index') -- project dashboard
                });
            });
        });
    });

    // Must be the last route to ensure no others match.
    this.route('missing', { path: '*path' });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this` doesn't have a property `organizationId` on it, Ember grabs that property from the model.

You can add a serialize hook to map `organizationId` to `id`

```
App.OrganizationsOrganizationRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  serialize:function(model){
    return { organizationId: Em.get(model, 'id')};
  }
})
```

Comment: While that makes sense in retrospect, that's not at all obvious when reading the guide. "The default serialize method inserts the model's id into the route's dynamic segment." The guide mentioned the `_id` convention before, but it doesn't really seem like those two concepts were linked.

Comment: There's a ton of guide to be expected to catch/know it all... http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_dynamic-segments